# Nested span in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to work with HTMLs having **span** inside another **span** in bootstrap for doing vertical alignment. I have so far used span for only making horizontal layout like putting "span4" thrice for creating a 3 column layout ..

but, Following lines create a vertical layout instead .. can some one point on how to use  nesting of span in bootstrap ..

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="row">

                <h4 class="span3 well">Related</h4>

                <div class="span3  well">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Related-1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Related-2</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're spanning 6 grid columns inside an element that spans only 4, which will necessarily cause wrapping. You always need to have child rows that total the same or fewer columns than parent rows if you don't want a vertical stack.

I suggest a closer look at the grid docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: isherwood- can we use above trick if we need vertical orientation instead of horizontal . i.e Related-1 and Related-2 to appear below Related. If i make span4 to span12 then they become horizontal. Is there any other way to get this vertical layout ?

Comment: What's wrong with this way? Your original question isn't very clear, and this one isn't either. Of course there are a hundred ways to make vertical layouts.

Comment: so there is nothing wrong in using span-wrapping for creating vertical layout.. that was basically the confusion ..

Comment: Not at all. You could also forgo Bootstrap span classes and simply float your elements left, for example, or give them a width and display them block.